# Why is AWS Patch-Manager support of Python 3.10 failing?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, aws-ssm

Back in April we found our Ubuntu 22.04 did not get patched due to no support at the time. This got rectified a week later by AWS, and patching  was successful in May.

Since then we are finding the following Python 3.10 error below. Futrther, when we attempt to patch - the whole source folder gets removed - 'patch-baseline-operations' - from the box. Boxes where this folder remains, are ones we haven't attempted to patch since May and that folder's timestamp is the May date - the last successful patch date. Does anyone have any idea what's going on or are seeing the same issues?

```
/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/jmespath/visitor.py:32: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if x is 0 or x is 1:
/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/jmespath/visitor.py:32: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if x is 0 or x is 1:
/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/jmespath/visitor.py:34: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  elif y is 0 or y is 1:
/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/jmespath/visitor.py:34: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  elif y is 0 or y is 1:
/var/log/amazon/ssm/patch-baseline-operations/jmespath/visitor.py:260: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if original_result is 0:
failed to run commands: exit status 1
```